# Solution of HMM

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, hidden-markov-model

Consider the following hidden markov model:

$X_t =F X_{t-1} + e_t$; $Z_t = H X_t + v_t$; $X_t \in \mathbb{R}^n, Z_t \in \mathbb{R}^m, e_t \sim N(0,Q), v_t \sim N(0,R)$.

Suppose that the process $X_t$ has unit roots. How does the presence of unit roots in the true Data-Generating Process affects evaluation of likelihood by Kalman filter and estimation of parameters $\theta$ ($F(\theta), H(\theta), R(\theta), Q(\theta)$)? Could you please be more specific in your answer and/or give reference to relevant literature regarding issues of consistency, rate of convergence, possible multimodality and etc. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of quotes from [this paper](http://Under%20regularity%20conditions,%20the%20maximum%20likelihood%20estimators%20of%20%CE%B8%20are%20consistent%20and%20asymptotically%20normal,%20with%20covariance%20matrix%20equal%20to%20the%20inverse%20of%20the%20asymptotic%20Fisher%20information%20matrix%20(see%20Caines,%201988).%20Besides%20the%20technical%20conditions%20regarding%20the%20existence%20of%20derivatives%20and%20their%20continuity%20about%20the%20true%20parameter,%20regularity%20requires%20that%20the%20model%20is%20identifiable%20and%20the%20true%20parameter%20values%20do%20not%20lie%20on%20the%20boundary%20of%20the%20parameter%20space.%20%20%20Pagan%20(1980)%20has%20derived%20sufficient%20conditions%20for%20asymptotic%20identifiability%20in%20stationary%20models%20and%20sufficient%20conditions%20for%20consistency%20and%20asymptotic%20normality%20of%20the%20maximum%20likelihood%20estimators%20in%20non%20stationary%20but%20asymptotically%20identifiable%20models.%20Strong%20consistency%20of%20the%20maximum%20likelihood%20estimator%20in%20the%20general%20case%20of%20a%20non%20compact%20parameter%20space%20is%20proved%20in%20Hannan%20and%20Deistler%20(1988).%20Recently,%20full%20asymptotic%20theory%20for%20maximum%20likelihood%20estimation%20of%20nonstationary%20state%20space%20models%20has%20been%20provided%20by%20Chang,%20Miller%20and%20Park%20(2009).). The first:

> Under regularity conditions, the maximum likelihood estimators of
>   $\theta$ are consistent and asymptotically normal, with covariance
>   matrix equal to the inverse of the asymptotic Fisher information
>   matrix (see Caines, 1988). Besides the technical conditions regarding
>   the existence of derivatives and their continuity about the true
>   parameter, regularity requires that the model is identifiable and the
>   true parameter values do not lie on the boundary of the parameter
>   space.

Number two:

> Pagan (1980) has derived sufficient conditions for asymptotic
>   identifiability in stationary models and sufficient conditions for
>   consistency and asymptotic normality of the maximum likelihood
>   estimators in non stationary but asymptotically identifiable models.
>   Strong consistency of the maximum likelihood estimator in the general
>   case of a non compact parameter space is proved in Hannan and Deistler
>   (1988). Recently, full asymptotic theory for maximum likelihood
>   estimation of nonstationary state space models has been provided by
>   Chang, Miller and Park (2009).

Your model isn't identifiable. This issue came up on an earlier thread [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160658/identifiability-of-a-state-space-model-dynamic-linear-model).